# defining a varible in a for loop inside a function

Tags: python-3.x, function, for-loop

I am trying to write the next function when i have some problem with the veriable i defined in the for loop:

```
def is_positive_int(st):
    x=0`enter code here`
    if len(st)>0:
        x=x+1
    for i in range(len(st)):
        if i ==0 and st[i] in range(1,10):
            x=x+1
        if i >0 and st[i] in range(0,10):
            x=x+1
    if x==3:
        return "True"
    else:
        return "false"
```

when I ran the code without the for loop( only with the first "if") I get the value of x i need to get. but with the "for" loop it does't working.
where am i wrong?

Comment: What's the content of `st`. Why do you think you are not getting the correct value of `x`?

Comment: What's your program try to achieve here?  Reading a list of numbers and determine if a number is positive or not?  Please read this first -https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask